# Can we override discovered orderer with defined orderer in connection profile?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to connect Hyperledger Explorer with my fabric network hosted on **Oracle Blockchain Service**. To my surprise, service discovery is finding an orderer that does not belong to my network and gets timed out while retrieving the data. After looking into the codebase, I found that any orderer defined in the `connection.yaml` is not looked up. Can we override the discovered orderer with the orderer defined in my `connection.yaml`?

Comment: For hyperledger-explorer, you can follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxNVyLP4YkI&list=PLSBNVhWU6KjW4qo1RlmR7cvvV8XIILub6&index=29

Answer (score 1):

Discovery returns the orderers from the channel configuration which is specified in the `configtx.yaml`.

Issue a config update transaction that changes the endpoints and it'll fix it.

Comment: Not sure if I can send that to Oracle Blockchain Service. I will try and will let you know!

Comment: Well, we can't for now, any other solution?